# How to run 2 setState hooks one after the other with a dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just starting to use hooks and I have this situation in a useEffect callback. I'd like to run the following 2 setState commands, the first will set the number of years someone is, the second will then use this years value to set the number of months they are.

It's an odd example but I'd basically like to know how I can make the 2nd setState run once the first has set a value for the number of years.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (personExists) {
    setYears(getPerson(person.name, person.dob));
    setMonths(getMonths(person.name, years);
}
}, [person]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've clearly noticed state is asynchronous and you get old state reads with your original code.

Just simply do the computation "locally" first, then set the values into state.

```
const newYears = getYears(person.name, person.dob);
const newMonths = getMonths(person.name, newYears);
setYears(newYears);
setMonths(newMonths);
```

The other option would be to use `useEffect` to make computing `months` a side effect of `years` changing, but that'll be harder to reason about.

It's also worth considering whether `years` and `months` here should be in state at all if they're not user-modifiable; you could instead use a memoized value:

```
const [years, months] = React.useMemo(() => {
  const years = getYears(person.name, person.dob);
  const months = getMonths(person.name, years);
  return [years, months];
}, [person]);
```

Comment: Ah ok, I wondered if there was some specific React convention or best practise for handling multiple setState commands which have dependencies on each other.

So in your example, the values would be worked out first then the setState would run? is there any chance the order gets messed up and 'undefined' get stored in state instead?

Comment: No, there's no chance of that if all the functions involved are synchronous (aside from cosmic rays messing up your CPU's instruction pointer to make it skip lines of code ;-) ). During the next render of the component, both `years` and `months` will have changed as requested (unless something else changes them before the next render).

Comment: Ha, I'm not sure what your 2nd example is, I don't know how useMemo works. Which method would you prefer, I'm not sure what you mean by memoized values here.

This is the first chance I get in the app to set these values and then use them to render UI in different parts of the flow.

Comment: If the user can't set manually set these values and you can always derive them from other data (in this case `person.name` and `person.dob`), they shouldn't be in state at all.  See here about useMemo: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: So the values come from a form which the user can go back and modify, I thought using state is the best approach here but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can split this in two useEffect, this way setMonths is called after years change. I also like the second approach of @AKZ

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (personExists) {
     setYears(getPerson(person.name, person.dob));
    }
}, [person]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (personExists) {
     setMonths(getMonths(person.name, years);
    }
}, [years]);
```